# JQUERY :: Auto Slideshow

Tags: jquery

I have a requirement where there were list of div's and to be auto moving one-by-one. I had the code where each ul/li is moving around from first slide to second. But I need to move the div one-by one instead of the entire slide.

HTML

```
 <div id="main">                        
       <div id="container">
        <div id="content_1">    
          <div id="slider">
            <ul>                
               <li>
                  <div style="width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid #000;float:left;">Div1 Content</div>
                  <div style="width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid #000;float:left;margin-left:20px;">Div2 Content</div>
                  <div style="width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid #000;float:left;margin-left:20px;">Div3 Content</div>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <div style="width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid #000;float:left;">Div1 Content</div>
                  <div style="width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid #000;float:left;margin-left:20px;">Div2 Content</div>
                  <div style="width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid #000;float:left;margin-left:20px;">Div3 Content</div>
               </li>
                <li>
                  <div style="width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid #000;float:left;">Div1 Content</div>
                  <div style="width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid #000;float:left;margin-left:20px;">Div2 Content</div>
                  <div style="width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid #000;float:left;margin-left:20px;">Div3 Content</div>
               </li>
            </ul>
           </div> 
         </div> 
       </div> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
 *, 
     *:before,
     *:after { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }

     #main { border:1px solid green; margin:0px auto; overflow:hidden; padding:15px; width:695px; }

     #container { margin:0 auto; position:relative; text-align:left; width:974px; margin-bottom:2em; }  

     #content_1 { position:relative; }          

     img { border:none; }

     pre { display:block; padding:10px; border:1px solid #bae2f0; background:#e3f4f9; margin:.5em 0; width:674px; }

     .graphic, #prevBtn, #nextBtn, #slider1prev, #slider1next { margin:0; padding:0; display:block; overflow:hidden; text-indent:-8000px; } /* image replacement */

     #prevBtn, #slider1prev { background:#c8c8c8; border:0px solid black; border-bottom-left-radius:10px; border-top-left-radius:10px;
     display:block; height:220px; left:-12px; padding-left:3px; padding-top:99px; position:absolute; top:26px; width:30px; z-index:1000; }

     #nextBtn, #slider1next { left:649px; padding-left:7px; background:#c8c8c8; border:0px solid black; border-bottom-right-radius:10px; border-top-right-radius:10px; 
     display:block; height:220px; padding-top:99px; position:absolute; top:26px; width:30px; z-index:1000; }

     #slider ul, #slider li, #slider2 ul, #slider2 li { margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; }

     #slider2 { margin-top:1em; }
```

SCRIPT

```
 $(document).ready(function()
                          { 
                            $("#slider").easySlider
                            ({
                              auto: true, 
                              continuous: true
                            });
                          });

         #slider li, #slider2 li { height:268px; overflow: hidden; width:993px; border:0px solid red; } 

     #prevBtn a, #nextBtn a, #slider1next a, #slider1prev a { display:block; position:relative; width:30px; height:77px; background:url([[pix:theme|left_icon]]) no-repeat 0 0; }   

     #nextBtn a, #slider1next a { background:url([[pix:theme|right_icon]]) no-repeat 0 0; }
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gansai/sojrezg9/)

Comment: Might I recommend reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Whenever you copy someone else's code that's been copyrighted - even if it's being used within the license terms, you should always include that information in the code - Even if it's just in a jsfiddle.  [Here's the owner of the plugin that you are using](https://github.com/Solutions-Nitriques/jQuery-easySlider/)

Answer (score 0):

With the jQuery [plugin](https://github.com/Solutions-Nitriques/jQuery-easySlider/) that you are using, you can't move individual `div`'s within a `li` tag.

The plugin is designed to have one slide per `li` tag, not multiple slides (`div`'s) per `li` tag.  Having multiple `div`'s per li tag is why you are seeing the results that you are.  It's moving all 3 `div`'s as a single slide, because that's what you're telling it to do.

This is what your HTML should look like:

```
<div id="slider">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div style="...;">Div1 Content</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div style="...;">Div2 Content</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div style="...;">Div3 Content</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Your JavaScript doesn't change.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#slider").easySlider
    ({
        auto: true,
        continuous: true
    });
});
```

And now the code works like it should.  Refer to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sojrezg9/1/)

Comment: I agree...but is there any alternate to move individual div's either by using li tag or without using li tag

Comment: @Could you please suggest me on moving individual div's one-by-one

Comment: @user2686207 - I guess I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish.  The code I provided moves only one `div` at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Timing Manager Helped me allot. It uses Javascript Promised. You just have to read the text in this page carefully.

https://sjp.co.nz/projects/timing-manager/

You need to have JSON skills for this.

I also used animation.css in combination.

If you can't implement it  I'll be happy to post the whole project in GitHub

Here is a more detailed explanation

https://github.com/sjp/TimingManager